# Express TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm refactoring my routes into a separate folder:

**server.js:**

```js
var express             = require("express"),
    parse               = require("body-parser"),
    db                  = require("mysql"),
    mailer              = require("nodemailer"),
    redirectToHTTPS     = require("express-http-to-https").redirectToHTTPS,
    app                 = express();
    
var indexRoutes         = require("./routes/index"),
    deviceRoutes        = require("./routes/devices"),
    locationRoutes      = require("./routes/locations"),
    organizationRoutes  = require("./routes/organizations");

app.use(parse.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));
app.use(redirectToHTTPS([/localhost:(\d{4})/], [/\/insecure/], 301));


//---------------------------------ROUTING--------------------------------------
app.use("/", indexRoutes);
app.use("/devices", deviceRoutes);
app.use("/locations", locationRoutes);
app.use("/organizations", organizationRoutes);


//-------------------------------SERVER INIT------------------------------------
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server initiated (port " + process.env.PORT + ")...");
});
```

**index.js (where my index routes are):**

```js
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = router;
```

**But,**

I am getting a TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

I have no idea what is going on, as a previous project I worked on had the exact same handling and had no issues whatsoever. I am using express 3.21.2.

Important to note that the error is in **all 4 of the route files**, I just happen to get the error in the index file since it is the first one.

Comment: It means that `router` is undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845431/cannot-read-property-of-get-undefined-in-the-express-router

Comment: Express 3.x is deprecated.

https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you're using version 3.x of Express [which doesn't include `express.Router()`](https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html#express) (so all subsequent usage of it in your routes files is invalid).  I'd encourage you to upgrade to the current version, 4.x, which is actively maintained.